# define an alias name for primary key in a model that is extended in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a `Stuff` Model like this :

```php
class Stuff extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'stuff_id';
    protected $fillable   = ['stuff_id' , 'title' , 'desc'];
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
}
```

In the other hand there is a `Product` model that extended from `Stuff` Model like this :

```php
class Product extends Stuff 
{
    protected $fillable   = ['quantity' , 'picture'];
}
```

As you can see beacause `Product` is extended from `Stuff` and primary key of `Stuff` is `stuff_id` ,  Anywhere that I want to call a `Product` instances and needs to print it's id should use a `$product->stuff_id` while I want use a clearer name for that like `$product->product_id`.

Is there any way that can define a alias primary key in child model that interpreted to `stuff_id` in back-end when running queries on database.

Comment: or just have a `$primaryKey = 'product_id'` on the Product model as well?

Comment: and to post a more defined answer, could you show some example code of how you would envision how you would handle the data if hyphothetically the code behind the scenes already worked?

Comment: Have you thought about Global scopes? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#query-scopes

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin, can you explain more as a answer with example?

Comment: @A.B.Developer I did using Scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To turn `product_id` into an alias of `stuff_id`:

```
...
$product->product_id // resolves to $product->stuff_id
...
public function getProductIdAttribute(): int
{
    return $this->stuff_id;
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `$primaryKey`, you can override the function that reads from that variable.

In your `Stuff` model, try adding something along the lines of:

```
/**
 * Get the primary key for the model.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getKeyName(): string
{
    return [
        Stuff::class => 'stuff_id',
        Product::class => 'product_id',
    ][get_class($this)];
}
```

And for reference, the default behavior: (`Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php`)

```
/**
 * Get the primary key for the model.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getKeyName()
{
    return $this->primaryKey;
}
```

Comment: Note that there is not a `product_id` field at all. I need an alias only in `Product` model that when call `product_id` considered as `stuff_id`.

Comment: Ah, in that case check my other answer:

Answer (score 1):

Using Global Scope:

```
//Say ProductScope.php
namespace App\Scopes;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class ProductScope implements Scope
{
    protected $model_name;
    public function __construct($model_name)
    {
        $this->model_name = $model_name;
    }

    /**
     * Apply the scope to a given Eloquent query builder.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $builder
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @return void
     */
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $attr = Schema::getColumnListing($this->model_name);

        $attr_ =  array_map(function ($item){
            return $item === 'stuff_id' ? $item.' as product_id' : $item;
        }, $attr);

        $builder->select($attr_);
    }
}
```

Then in the Product Model:

```
use App\Scopes\ProductScope;

class Product extends Stuff
{
    protected $table = 'stuffs';
    protected $primaryKey = 'stuff_id';
    /**
     * The "booting" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope(new ProductScope('stuffs'));
    }
}
```

This will replace the `stuff_id` with `product_id`